# Read JHOVE attributes From TIFF And JPEG-2000 Files using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tiff, python-2.x, jpeg2000

I am trying to read JHOVE attribues from TIFF and JP2 files.  Is there a python library that makes this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [tifflib python](https://code.google.com/p/pylibtiff/) binding (for TIFF file) and [jpylyzer](https://github.com/openplanets/jpylyzer) (for JP2 file). You should be able to extract all meta data from the input file, just select the one you need.